# How do I iterate through a string contained in a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

For clarity, I am not asking how to iterate through a vector of strings (which is what all of my searches turn up), I want to iterate through a string contained in a vector of strings. I'm running into linker errors when trying to assign the string iterator a value from a string in a vector.

The code below takes a reference to a const vector of strings. The purpose of the function is to reverse the order of the letters and the elements so if you passed in a vector of strings containing { "abc", "def", "ghi" } it would reorder them and return a vector of strings containing { "ihg", "fed", "cba" }. It should be noted that the function is declared as static in the header file. I'm running into a problem when I try to attempt to initialize the string iterator in the for loop. I get a linker error:

```
"No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<char*>'
```

I thought accessing rbegin() through the -> from the vector iterator would work but... I'm stumped. Why does stringsVectorIterator->rend() cause a linker error when assigned to string::reverse_iterator rit?

```
vector<string>  StringUtility::reverse(const vector<string> &strings)
{
    // Create a vector of strings with the same size vector as the one being passed in.
    vector<string> returnValue( strings.size() );
    vector<string>::const_reverse_iterator stringsVectorIterator;
    size_t returnVectorCounter;

    for (stringsVectorIterator = strings.rbegin(), returnVectorCounter = 0;
         stringsVectorIterator != strings.rend();
         stringsVectorIterator++, returnVectorCounter++)
    {
        // the problem is in the initialization of the string iterator, it creates
        // a linker error.
        for (string::reverse_iterator rit = stringsVectorIterator->rbegin();
             rit != stringsVectorIterator->rend();
             ++rit)
        {
            returnValue[returnVectorCounter].push_back(*rit);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
};
```

Comment: Is that really a _linker_ error?

Comment: This definitely showed up as a linker error in XCode v 6.2

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Sure it wasn't a compiler error?

Comment: Oops... you're of course correct. Not a linker error. As I was saying, this definitely did not show up as a linker error... ;)

Answer (score 5):

`stringsVectorIterator` is a `const` iterator, so its target string is `const`. This means you can't get a non-`const` iterator over the string.

Change the inner loop:

```
 for (string::const_reverse_iterator rit = ...
              ^^^^^^
```

and all should be well.

In C++11 or later, you could use `auto` to avoid these hassles.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that was an easy fix. I guess I made the assumption that in a const vector of strings it was the vector that was const, but the strings could still be modified. It looks like the scope of a vector's constness applies to everything contained within if I'm understanding it correctly.